# How do I perform a looped server httpclient

Tags: android, httpclient

I am looking for a solution to do a looped http client to a server with a pause between each execution of a .php file. I then want on each loop for a text view to update with the specific information. However I am doing this

```
while (!endOfCommands) {

runCommand();

try {
     Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch() {}

 ....
inside my runCommand() {

      //Access the server with an http client. 
      MyTextView.setText(newCommand.getID());



}
```

In this particular case, the text view does not update until after all the commands have run through and I cannot get the text view to increment like 1, 2, 3, 4, ... instead it goes from 1 to 4 skipping 2 & 3

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you must be running this loop on the *event dispatch thread* (the "EDT"), the thread that's responsible for updating the screen. While it's running your loop, it can't do the work of repainting. In general you shouldn't do any long-running tasks on the EDT -- you should always create a new background thread to do them.